# react-scripts build then serve is serving html, not the main.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, serve, react-scripts

I am using `react-scripts` and successfully ran `npm run build` to generate the `build` folder.

I then went to serve it locally by using the serve npm package by running `serve -s build`.

`serve` then runs on port 5000, which is good.

When I go to access the page at `localhost:5000` the page just stalls out and the following error is in the console `main.975cb3de.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` .

I open the `main.975cb3de.js` file in the console and it is trying to serve the `index.html` file.

If I empty browser cache and reload the page then it loads fine. This happens every time I run a build.

I have a suspicion that there is a configuration in the `serve` library but not too sure.

Any thoughts on why it tries to serve HTML first time around and how to fix this?

Comment: Apparently there is a Syntax error on your code somewhere, try looking out for any problems in the dev environment before building your app.

Comment: @GiovanniKleinCampigoto I don't believe there is a syntax error. When I run it the first time only it gives this error. If I run using `react-scripts start` everything works fine, but it does not run from the build directory, which makes me think it is not a syntax error.

Comment: What happens if you delete the build folder, and run the build command again?

Comment: Still same issue. It's weird that the main.js file in the /build is trying to serve the index.html file. It's only on the first time the page is hit after a build, once the user refreshes it's fine. This happens on multiple computers.

Comment: Maybe you should try to build your app using yarn, it's recomended for CRA apps: https://yarnpkg.com/

Comment: @GiovanniKleinCampigoto I just updated `serve` package to the latest version and it is working now...thanks for your help. I probably should use yarn from here on out too.

Comment: No problem, :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by updating the `serve` package to version `6.5.6` **and** utilizing the `--cache` flag when running serve.

1. `npm update -g serve`

Turns out that when using the `-s` flag with serve, there is a default caching of 1 day. I had to disable this cache, which fixed the problem.

2. `serve -s ./build --cache=-1`

The second command was most critical in fixing the issue.